# need help using dll in Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to use an dll, i added a reference to it and then tried to use it in my project, but it says that it doesnt recognize the name space. Sorry i am not really experienced.

[image: image link]

Comment: did you compiled it ? before adding reference

Comment: @ZaidMirza : I don't think he could add it as a reference otherwise. Yet I doubt the namespace even is `Fasm.NET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`using` directive**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) requires a namespace. Namespaces are separated by dots, making `Fasm.NET` two namespaces where `NET` would be a child of `Fasm`, which I guess is not the case for the library. The IntelliSense menu should show you examples of existing namespaces once you type the first character(s).

Though, judging from the [**Fasm library's sources**](https://github.com/ZenLulz/Fasm.NET/blob/master/Fasm.NET/Fasm.NET.cpp) it seems the complete namespace is:

```
Binarysharp.Assemblers.Fasm
```

Try that in your `using` statement and it should work.

Comment: thanks, that worked.How do i find out the namespaces in general? what did i do so stupidly wrong to deserves the downvotes?

Comment: @battler11 : If you don't have the source code and no documentation to tell you the namespace name you just have to go on trial and error. Type one or a few letters and see what IntelliSense suggests to you (or type nothing if it comes up automatically after `using`), then look for any namespaces that are not the standard ones (like your project namespace, or `System`, etc.).

Comment: @battler11 : If I may guess the reason for the downvotes (I'm not one of them) I'd say that it is because your question lacks details (details such as what the library is and where you got it from) _and also_ because you only posted an image of your problem. There's not much of a description of your problem. -- If you ask me though, the downvote system is highly overused.

Comment: @battler11 : Here are a few tips I can give you to help you write a more "accepted" question: **1)** Avoid writing the language or IDE you use in the title (with [a few exceptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)). The tags exists for a reason, which is to specify languages, methods, APIs, etc. that are related to your question. **2)** Always do your best to write in a formal, grammatically correct manner. **3)** Try to avoid saying thanks (yes I'm serious, some people react to this).

Comment: ok, i will try better next time.

Comment: @battler11 : Sorry, I couldn't put everything in one comment :). -- **4)** Avoid apologizes and instead just say your apology as a plain statement, or not at all. **5)** Whenever possible show all **necessary** code, research and **complete** error messages. **6)** Sum your question in your title. Don't say "I need help" or something like that, get us interested in your question and give us a hint what it's about.

Comment: @battler11 : `ok, i will try better next time.` - Just don't feel like I'm picking at you right now, I do this purely because I want help. And don't be scared of my long list of tips, nor the people on this forum. Some are harsh, but there will always also be the ones that simply only want to help. -- Every user that has 2000 reputation or more also have the ability to freely edit questions and answers, which very many do in order to help improve one's question and increase the chance of better answers (users below 2k rep can also do this but we have to accept the edits first).